# Javascript+mysql "simple quote"

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, sql-like

How to solve this error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\'%VALUE%\' LIMIT 60 , 20' at line 1

The problematic code is

```
  var nombreBuscado = $('input[name=nombreBuscado]').val();
    if (nombreBuscado !== "") {

    statement = " VIEW WHERE COLUMN  LIKE  " + "\'%" + nombreBuscado + "%\'" ;
}
```

the sql malformed is

```
SELECT * FROM VIEW WHERE COLUMN LIKE \'%VALUE%\' LIMIT 60 , 20
```

EDITED
 the select is over the view, and I check case sensitive

Comment: shouldn't you print `'\%VALUE%\'` instead of `\'%VALUE%\'` ?

Comment: Did you managed to make it work?

Comment: this still does not work, I'll change the question to indicate that is a view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have something like this:

```
var nombreBuscado = $('input[name=nombreBuscado]').val();
    if (nombreBuscado !== "") {

    statement=" VST_ContribuyentesConPV WHERE NOM_CONTRIBUYENTE LIKE  " 
                + "'%" + nombreBuscado + "%'" ;
}
```

Using `'` you don't have to escape it since you are sinside a double quote delimited string. This will print:

```
SELECT * FROM VST_ContribuyentesConPV WHERE NOM_CONTRIBUYENTE LIKE '%VALUE%'
```

If you want to use doublequotes, then you have to escape them:

```
var nombreBuscado = $('input[name=nombreBuscado]').val();
    if (nombreBuscado !== "") {

    statement=" VST_ContribuyentesConPV WHERE NOM_CONTRIBUYENTE LIKE  " 
                + "\"%" + nombreBuscado + "%\"" ;
}
```

This will output:

```
SELECT * FROM VST_ContribuyentesConPV WHERE NOM_CONTRIBUYENTE LIKE "%VALUE%"
```

One last option would be to replace all your `"` with `'`. This would make the escaping (`\'`) work:

```
var nombreBuscado = $('input[name=nombreBuscado]').val();
    if (nombreBuscado !== "") {

    statement=' VST_ContribuyentesConPV WHERE NOM_CONTRIBUYENTE LIKE  ' 
                + '\'%' + nombreBuscado + '%\'' ;
}
```

<kbd>[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qUdx9/1/)</kbd>